# How to dump out an array of pixels as a png?

Tags: macos, image, png

I'm on MacOSX.

I have read out an image, as

```
char image[WIDTH][HEIGHT][3]; // row, col, rgb value
```

Now, I want to dump it out as a png file. What is the quickest way to do this?

Comment: Can you explain why you are declaring this as a char type?

Comment: The way I'm reading it back via glReadPixels ; however, I may be doing this wrong. What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: a char array just seems wrong. It should be a bit array, but I am not an OS X expert. I can only go on my experience with images from other frameworks.

Comment: @Jeremy: In C, `char` is usually 8 bits, and is most often the correct type to use. Certainly, nobody should be using an array of `bool`!

Comment: certainly not bool. char just seems weird to me. I tend to keep my work in c# which has a lot more typing features than C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://zarb.org/~gc/html/libpng.html <-- amazing tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [libpng](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/libpng.html). I don't have a Mac, so I can't tell you if it's already pre-installed, but it should be! :-)

Answer (score 1):

You could make it a bit stream and write the bitstream to an image object and then you can save the image object as a PNG.

Comment: Can you give me more details?